# Unable to style cells with xlsx-js-style for SheetJS

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

I am using SheetJS community version in combination with the xlsx-js-style package in order to add styles to the cells.

The SheetJS part works fine, I get my Excel file as intended. But when I try to add a style to a cell (following xlsx-js-style documentation), no style is applied. I do not get any errors either.

This is what I tried (the part that doesn't work is //style A1 cell):

```
    //define column order
    var headers = ["fullname", "currentcompany", "currentjobtitle", "statusid", "location", "comments", "linkedinurl", "mobilenumber", "email"]

    //create worksheet and workbook
    var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(filteredProfiles, { header: headers, origin: "A4" });
    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Sheet1");

    //add custom header names
    let Heading = [['Name', 'Company', 'Title', 'Status', 'Location', 'Comments', 'Profile', 'Phone', 'Email']];
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, Heading, { origin: 'A4' });

    //set cols/rows width and height
    ws['!cols'] = [];
    ws['!rows'] = [];

    ws['!cols'] = [
        { 'width': 30 }, // width for col A
        { 'width': 30 }, // width for col B
    ];

    ws['!rows'] = [
        { 'hpt': 60 },// height for row 1
        { 'hpt': 20 },]; //height for row 2


    //add title in A1
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, [
        ["Recent profiles"]
    ], { origin: "A1" });

    //define current date
    let today = new Date();
    let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    let MM = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    //add current date in A2
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, [
        [`${dd}/${MM}/${yyyy}`]
    ], { origin: "A2" });


    //style A1 cell
    ws["A1"].s = {
        font: {
            name: "Calibri",
            sz: 24,
            bold: true,
            color: { rgb: "FFFFAA00" },
        },
    };


    //generate XLSX file and trigger a download 
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, "data.xlsx");
```

Comment: I also tried the "Cell Style Example" from the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-js-style    Same result: the file is created but I have no styles applied in Excel

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I was missing const XLSX = require('sheetjs-style'); before the code I posted. Now it works.